# resolution for intents with no action

Tags: android, android-intent

According to the Android docs (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html): "On the other hand, an Intent object that doesn't specify an action automatically passes the test — as long as the filter contains at least one action."
and "every category in the Intent object must match a category in the filter. The filter can list additional categories, but it cannot omit any that are in the intent."

I have an intent filter declared as follows:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="my.custom.action" />                
    <category android:name="my.custom.category" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Based on the rules above I expect the parent activity of this filter to be returned with the following code, but it is not:

```
List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
    new Intent().addCategory("my.custom.category"), 
    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY + PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);
```

Will the intent resolution return an activity with the filter above if no action is specified?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your example the main problem is in `PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY + PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER`, you have to do `|` ("bitwise or") to make it work. I mean you have to write something like `PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY | PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER` this.

Comment: See my comment above. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the two flags together with the '+' sign is most likely the problem.

```
setFlags(PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY + 
PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);
```

This is the way I would do it instead:

```
setFlags(PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY|
PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);
```

Comment: The result is the same. Also (0x10000 + 0x40) == (0x10000 | 0x40).

Comment: Checking the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/com/android/server/IntentResolver.java#IntentResolver.queryIntent%28android.content.Intent%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cboolean%29) it seems that intents that only include categories are not resolved to any filters. The Android documentation quoted in the original post seems to be wrong.